# Matlab: confusion in generating binary numbers with a specific probability distribution

Tags: matlab, random

I want to obtain an array of binary numbers of length say `N=10` where the probability of `0` = 0.6 and probability of 1's is 0.4. But, during validating if actually the probability is correct, I am getting incorrect probability values. So, `symbols` is an array of 0/1 integers generated. Then I am checking if the probability is correct or not using `p_1 = sum(symbols==1)/length(symbols)` .Where am I going wrong?

```
    N =10;
    p_0 = 0.6;% probability of zeros
  *for n = 1:N
         xr=rand;
         if xr<p_0
             symbols(n)=1;
         else
             symbols(n)=0;
         end
end

        p_1 = sum(symbols==1)/length(symbols)
        p_0 = 1-p_1*
```

Comment: Check your math. Your given parameter is only the expected average (there is still variance from run to run; a result completely filled with 1's is possible). Easy solution: fill first 60% of some array with 0's, the remaining with ones. Shuffle (random-permutation)!

Comment: @sascha: could you please elaborate your comment as an answer? thank you for the idea.

Comment: No sorry. As i'm not much of a matlab-user, i won't go into details (and present code). [randperm](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) is all you need. Just fill the ordered array (which represents the probabilities) and use randperm's permutation (only indirect usage compared to other languages as randperm just takes 1 param: N -> n-indices in permutation) as indices to access a shuffled result.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43099536/2166798 for an explanation of why 10 bits are nowhere near enough to draw meaningful conclusions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confusion lies in understanding probability and not in Matlab. You are using the built-in function `rand`, which generates *uniformly* distributed values between `0..1`. When you test the hypothesis that the values are less than some threshold, you generate a new distribution. The code is correct.

`observations = rand(N, 1) > p_0`

produces a distribution of `1`s and `0`s as you state. As you increase `N` you will find that the empirical results,

`p_1 = sum(observations == 1)`

consistently approaches your expected value of `0.4`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if the probability is correct, generate an array with a million values. Out of 10 random values, it is impossible to know that the underlying probabilities are.

Note that you can do what you are doing without a loop:

```
symbols = rand(N,1) > p_0;
```

(This generates a logical array, `+symbols` would be a numeric array.)